# my localstorage font size not working initially

Tags: javascript, fonts, size

my localstorage font size + - well in general, however, after loading initially font size + 2 get string value, for example, initial font size (16) + 2 = 162. 
I think the initial size value should be a variable, not a mere string.  However, the initial font size, localstorage getitem value is a string. 
After then it works well. How can I convert the initial font size value into a variable?
Thank you in advance for your answer.

```
<div id="font-size-change">
    <span class="font-size-label">font size</span>
    <button id="fs_up">+</button>
    <span id="fs_write" style="width:15px;"></span>
    <button id="fs_down">-</button>
</div>

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {  // === Font Size Control =============================================================
  var reset = $('#stx').css('fontSize'); // Grab the default font size  
  var elm = $('#stx'); // Font resize these elements
  var size = localStorage.getItem('size');
  var size = parseInt(size, 10);

  if (size) {
    elm.css('font-size', size + 'px');
    $( "#fs_write" ).text(size); // 
  } else {    
    size = str_replace(reset, 'px', ''); //set the default font size and remove px from the value
    $( "#fs_write" ).text(size); // 
  }  

    var min = 12; //min  
    var max = 56; //max 
    var p = 4; //increase
    var m = 4; //decrease

  $('#fs_up').click(function() { //Increase font size

    if (size <= max) { //if the font size is lower or equal than the max value 
      size = size + p; //increase the size     
      elm.css({ //set the font size
    'fontSize': size
      });
     $( "#fs_write" ).text(size); // 
      localStorage.setItem('size', size);
    }    
    return false; //cancel a click event
  });

  $('#fs_down').click(function() {    
    if (size >= min) { //if the font size is greater or equal than min value     
      size = size - m; //decrease the size    
      elm.css({ //set the font size
    'fontSize': size
      });
     $( "#fs_write" ).text(size); // 
      localStorage.setItem('size', size);
    }   
    return false; //cancel a click event
  });

  $('#fs_write').click(function() { //Reset the font size   
    elm.css({ //set the default font size 
      'fontSize': reset
    });
     size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');
     $( "#fs_write" ).text(size); // 
      localStorage.setItem('size', size);
  });

});

//A string replace function
function str_replace(haystack, needle, replacement) {
  var temp = haystack.split(needle);
  return temp.join(replacement);
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Explanation:**

It's because the `+` operator is used both as an arithmithic operator (if both operands are numbers), and as a string concatenation operator (if at least one of the operand is a string).

Your `size` variable is initially a number as you are using `parseInt` at the begining of your code to get its value. But in the `#fs_write` click event listener you tranform it back into a string:

```
size = str_replace(reset, 'px', '');     // size is now a string because the return value of str_replace is a string
```

then when the `#fs_up` click happens, you add `p` to `size` (which is now a string):

```
size = size + p;                         // string concatenation is chosen over arithmitic addition because one of the operands (size) is a string
```

which causes the problem.

**Solution:**

Just transform `size` into a number before using the `+` operator using: `Number`, `parseInt` or the `unary +` operator:

```
size = +size + p;                        // using the unary + (now size is a number and p is also a number thus the arithmitic addidtion is chosen over the string concatenation)
// or
size = Number(size) + p;                 // using Number
```

**Notes:**

1. The `#fs_down` click event listener doen't cause the problem because the `-` operator is used only as an arithmitic operator. So when one or both operands is a string, it is automatically used as a number (`"55" - "10" === 45` but `"55" + 10 === "5510"`).
2. You are redeclaring `size` at the begining of your code wich is unecessary. Leave the first `var size = ...;` and use the second `size = ...;` whithout the `var`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It helped me perfectly!